# SQL Statement/ Codeigniter appointment booking

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, appointment

I am working on a booking software with a daily calendar. I have four tables as follows:

```
Services:
ID | EmployeeID| ServiceID| RoomID| StartDate        | EndDate
1  |     1     |     1    |   2   | 2017-06-18 01:00 |2017-06-18 02:00
2  |     2     |     1    |   1   | 2017-06-18 03:00 |2017-06-18 04:00

Employees: 
EmployeeID | Name
    1      |  A
    2      |  B
    3      |  C

Rooms:
RoomID | Name
  1    |  X
  2    |  Y
  3    |  Z

EmpBreaks: 
ID | EmployeeID | BreakStart       | BreakEnd
1  |     1      | 2017-06-18 02:00 | 2017-06-18 03:00
```

Where the Services table stores the booked appointment details, the Employees tables contains a list of all the Employees, Rooms Table contains list of all Rooms, and the EmpBreaks stores all the times when the Employee is not available.

I want to perform a query to search for all available employees and rooms on a specified start and end date.

For Example:

Start Date '2017-06-18 01:30'
End Date '2017-06-18 02:30'

Result:

EmployeeID {3}

RoomID {1,3}

Here is updated working code.

```
function check_available_rooms_therapists() {
        $this->data['message'] = array();
        $this->data['success'] = FALSE;

    $post = $this->input->post();

    $EmployeeFields = array(
        'Employees.EmployeeID',
        'Employees.Name'
    );

    $sDate = $post['StartDate'];
    $eDate = $post['EndDate'];

    $whereEmp = "Employees.EmployeeID NOT IN (SELECT Services.EmployeeID FROM Services where 
        (( '" . $sDate . "' BETWEEN Services.StartDate AND Services.EndDate) or  
        ( '" . $eDate . "' BETWEEN Services.StartDate AND Services.EndDate) or
        (Services.StartDate BETWEEN '". $sDate ."' AND '" . $eDate ."') or
        (Services.EndDate BETWEEN '". $sDate ."' AND '" . $eDate ."')) union
        (SELECT EMPBREAKS.EMPID FROM EMPBREAKS WHERE(
        ('" . $sDate . "' BETWEEN EMPBREAKS.StartB AND EMPBREAKS.EndB) or 
        ('" . $eDate . "' BETWEEN EMPBREAKS.StartB AND EMPBREAKS.EndB) or 
        (EMPBREAKS.StartB BETWEEN '" . $eDate . "' AND '" . $sDate ."') or
        (EMPBREAKS.EndB BETWEEN '" . $eDate . "' AND '" . $sDate ."'))))";

    $this->db->select($EmployeeFields);
    $listing = $this->db->get_where('Employees', $whereEmp, 50 , 0);
    $result = $listing -> result();

    $avEmpName = array();
    $avEmpID = array();

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $avEmpID[] = $row->EmployeeID;
        $avEmpName[] = $row->Name;
    }

    $RoomFields = array(
        'Rooms.RoomID',
        'Rooms.Name'
    );

     $whereRoom = "Rooms.RoomID not in (SELECT Services.RoomID FROM Services WHERE 
        ((Services.startdate BETWEEN '" . $sDate . "' AND '" . $eDate. "') OR 
            (Services.enddate BETWEEN '" . $sDate . "' AND '" . $eDate. "') OR 
            ('" .$sDate . "' BETWEEN  Services.startdate AND Services.enddate) OR
            ('" .$eDate . "' BETWEEN  Services.startdate AND Services.enddate)))";

    $this->db->select($RoomFields);
    // $this->db->from('Rooms');
    $Rooms = $this->db->get_where('Rooms', $whereRoom, 50 ,0);
    $Rresult = $Rooms -> result();

    $avRoomName = array();
    $avRoomID = array();

    foreach ($Rresult as $r) {
        $avRoomID[] = $r->RoomID;
        $avRoomName[] = $r->Name;
    }

        $this->data['EmployeeID'] =  $avEmpID;
        $this->data['RoomID'] = $avRoomID;
        $this->data['RoomName'] = $avRoomName;
        $this->data['Name'] = $avEmpName;

    $this->data['success'] = TRUE;
    echo json_encode($this->data);
    die;
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can split your problem easily in two different queries ,

First, you can write a query who is matching everything you want exclude ,
let's call it **wrong result** ,
after that you can get all the employees and rooms from **Employee** and **Rooms** table who are **not in** the **wrong result**

```
select * from Employees
where Employees.EmployeeID not in (
SELECT a.EmployeeID
    FROM Appointments a
    where  ((a.startdate BETWEEN yourstartdate AND yourenddate ) or  (a.enddate BETWEEN yourstartdate AND yourenddate)));

select * from Rooms
where Rooms.RoomID not in (
    SELECT a.RoomID
    FROM Appointments a
    where  ((a.startdate BETWEEN yourstartdate AND yourenddate ) or  (a.enddate BETWEEN yourstartdate AND yourenddate)));
```

Comment: It seems I did not explain my question clearly. I've updated my question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I wanted. Thanks

Comment: you are welcome , sorry but yesterday was a bit difficult to understand your question before edit ! Another suggestion you can use **DISTINCT** in the sub query

Comment: Thanks. I updated the code in my question with working sql statement since the code you provided needed some tweaks for it to work exactly as I wanted. In addition we need to check a.startdate BETWEEN yourstartdate AND yourenddate

Answer (score 0):

Working SQL Statements:

```
SELECT `Employees`.`EmployeeID`, `Employees`.`Name`
FROM (`Employees`)
WHERE `Employees`.`EmployeeID` NOT IN (SELECT Services.EmployeeID FROM Services where 
 (( yourstartdate BETWEEN Services.StartDate AND Services.EndDate) or 
 ( yourenddate BETWEEN Services.StartDate AND Services.EndDate) or
 (Services.StartDate BETWEEN yourstartdate AND yourenddate) or
 (Services.EndDate BETWEEN yourstartdate AND yourenddate)) union
 (SELECT EMPBREAKS.EMPID FROM EMPBREAKS WHERE(
 (yourstartdate BETWEEN EMPBREAKS.StartB AND EMPBREAKS.EndB) or 
 (yourenddate BETWEEN EMPBREAKS.StartB AND EMPBREAKS.EndB) or 
 (EMPBREAKS.StartB BETWEEN yourenddate AND yourstartdate) or
 (EMPBREAKS.EndB BETWEEN yourenddate AND yourstartdate))))
```

AND

```
SELECT `Rooms`.`RoomID`, `Rooms`.`Name`
FROM (`Rooms`)
WHERE `Rooms`.`RoomID` not in (SELECT Services.RoomID FROM Services WHERE 
 ((Services.startdate BETWEEN 'yourstartdate AND yourenddate) OR 
 (Services.enddate BETWEEN 'yourstartdate AND yourenddate) OR 
 ('yourstartdate BETWEEN Services.startdate AND Services.enddate) OR
 (yourenddate BETWEEN Services.startdate AND Services.enddate)))
```